# SQL: How to notify user if duplicates are found (using WHERE NOT EXISTS clause)?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

I am filling a table with data using a stored procedure, and checking for duplicates with the `WHERE NOT EXISTS`-clause.

Something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyProcedure]
    @param udtMyUserDefinedTableType
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblMyTable
        SELECT
            Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5
    FROM @param
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                       FROM tblMyTable i
                       INNER JOIN @param o
                       ON i.Column1 = o.Column1
                       AND i.Column3 = o.Column3
                       AND i.Column5 = o.Column5 )
END
```

As is, my application adds the data, and skips the duplicates: **good**.

But I would like for the the user to be notified if and when a duplicate row is skipped.
Preferably, which exact lines. Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you just add a `SELECT` *before you do the insert*, like:

```
SELECT 'Not inserted:', Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5 
  FROM @param AS o
  WHERE EXISTS
  ( 
    SELECT 1
      FROM dbo.tblMyTable AS i
      WHERE i.Column1 = o.Column1
        AND i.Column3 = o.Column3
        AND i.Column5 = o.Column5 
  );

-- also the insert can be slightly simpler:

INSERT INTO dbo.tblMyTable(column list)
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5
  FROM @param AS o
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                       FROM dbo.tblMyTable AS i
                       WHERE i.Column1 = o.Column1
                         AND i.Column3 = o.Column3
                         AND i.Column5 = o.Column5 );
```

Of course you'll want to have error handling and wrap this in a transaction to prevent race conditions etc.

Comment: Mr. @Aaron Bertrand, thanks for your comment.
I appreciate the tips in how to simplify and compact my code!
But I am not seeing how these changes will send a notification to my user if and when duplicates are skipped?
I am obviously missing something someone with more experience than me would pick up on :-) Please, if you would elaborate. (My application runs as before after I added your code)

Comment: @OleM I think you need to clarify what you mean by "send a notification." I assumed you wanted to show the caller of the procedure the rows that were not inserted; this does that (but your app will also have to be changed to consume that result and display it to the user). If you mean something else, like send them an e-mail, you need to explain.

Comment: ah, of course. Sorry about that. I am very new to SQL. I am working in WPF (.NET). So I was looking for a message that would be sent to my user in the GUI. I feel foolish, as I didn't mention that, nor add a tag for WPF.
Let me instead ask; what is `(column list)` in your example- I couldn't execute unless I removed it.

Comment: @OleM it is best practice to [always include the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) instead of blindly telling SQL Server `INSERT table SELECT ...`. So you should replace it with the list of columns you're inserting to in `dbo.tblMyTable`, in the correct order. And yeah, SQL Server knows nothing about your application and how to display messages there, you'll have to code that from the app side.

Comment: TSQL does not send "messages" to "users". Your application does that. So the question should be based on the logic you currently have which builds the rows in your UDT and calls the stored procedure. The suggestion here is that your procedure return a resultset containing the "duplicates". Your application would then "do something" with that information if that resultset is not empty.